# Relationship between CDocument and CPropertySheet

Tags: mfc, relationship, mdi

I have a `CPropertySheet` instance which is initialized using `DoModal()` in one of the methods of my `CDocument` class, in an MDI MFC application

My problem is I would like to refresh the view associated with the document from the sheet without ending the `DoModal()`.

How do I get an handle back to the `CDocument` from my `CPropertySheet` so I can manipulated the `CView` easily ?

I have tried different things from this MSDN article but I am not able to retrieve what I want http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs315d2c.aspx

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SendMessage or PostMessage to the target window. Do this when the apply button is clicked.

Refer: http://cppandmfc.blogspot.com/2012/08/mfc-creating-and-using-property-page.html

You will get a Nice idea from that writeup